# HealthKit search Samples by "Date Added to Health"

Tags: swift, healthkit

Is there a way to get samples from HealthKit filtered by the "Date Added to Health"? I want to get every sample which has a newer "Date Added to Health"-Date than the last time I searched for them.

I just know the way to search for the "Start Date" and "End Date" but it can happen, that someone adds a sample for the past ([example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDCCk.png)).

```
// Predicate to search by "Start Date" and "End Date"
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(fromDate, endDate: toDate, options: .None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use an [HKAnchoredObjectQuery](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKAnchoredObjectQuery_Class/index.html). The first time you make this query, you pass in a nil anchor. When you get your results, you store the returned anchor somewhere persistent (NSUserDefaults, CoreData, etc). The next time you make a query you pass in the anchor you saved instead of nil, which will return all items that were entered into HealthKit since your anchor was generated and that match your query's predicate.